Error Loading "sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2"
I have built a document question-answering system using llama-2, but while downloading the embedding model, I am getting an OSError.
OSError: We couldn't connect to 'https://huggingface.co' to load this file, couldn't find it in the cached files and it looks like sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 is not the path to a directory containing a file named config.json. Checkout your internet connection or see how to run the library in offline mode at 'https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/installation#offline-mode'.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Based on what you sent,

I suggest you double-check your working directory.
Try downloading the files directly from the website:(https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2/tree/main.) and placing them in the project folder:

From my experience, it was either incomplete or corrupt.
Once you are done re-route the path to the folder and run it.
Hope this helps.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review
